# Create NICE (Random) path between 2 points X and Y positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, position

Using: Javascript, kinetic.js on HTML5 Canvas

Hi

I have done a lot of searching and testing other suggestions I have found but none have seemed to work out for me.

I am trying to create an array of x and y containing objects something like this:

```
{x:695 , y:363},{x:774 , y:609},{x:654 , y:42},{x:991 , y:213},{x:788 , y:172}
```

I want to draw these points (about 70 - 100) on canvas and map a line between them. My points have a definitive start point and end point and what i mean in the title "NICE" is something like this:

[image: Map with tracker canvas]

As you see by the image (created by defining points) the line is wavy and not really intersecting, this is what i mean by nice!

I don't want to create just a direct path.

I have tried various ways to create the random points between the 2 main points but i just end up with a total mess

[image: not looking pretty]

Here is the latest attempt:

```
var path;

  while (count) {
   randomx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1280) + 0;  
   randomy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 720) + 0;

  obj = []
  obj['x']= randomx;
  obj['y']= randomy;

  path.push(obj);
  count--;
  }

  function custom_compare (a,b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
  }

  path.sort(custom_compare).reverse();

  obj = []
  obj['x']= 486;
  obj['y']= 54;
  path.push(obj);
```

I guess I already knew this was not going to work but i have tried so many ways to create a similar path to the one in my first image.

If anyone might advise me how best to create this path it would be really helpful

Thanks